# Why SSIS packages are saved into PackageName______V0.7z archive?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

I am working on an SSIS 2019 solution with ten DTSX packages (let say `Package1.dtsx`, `Package2.dtsx`, ...).

I noticed that inside the folder of the solution there are some files named

- Package1______V0.7z
- Package1______V0.7z
- Package1______V2.7z
- Package1______V3.7z

Each 7Z archive contains only the file `Package1.dtsx`. It looks like it is an older version of the package but why VS generated them? Can I delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless something *very* special is happening with your install, that's nothing Visual Studio/SSDT is doing out of the box. If those files are getting generated with current timestamps, I'd look at the project and see whether there are pre/post build steps 7-zipping the packages as some terrible source control step.